# com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method

Tags: java, spring

I just want to create an object of class, but got this error when debugging. Can anybody tell me what the problem is? The location of this code is in some Spring(2.5) Service class.

There is a similar problem: [OJB Reference Descriptor 1:0 relationship? Should I set auto-retrieve to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702707/ojb-reference-descriptor-10-relationship-should-i-set-auto-retrieve-to-false/4123482#4123482)

Thanks a lot~

Comment: It's kinda hard to guess what your problem is without any source code or stack trace.

Comment: I figured it out, the toString()  method of the class may throw NullPointerException if invoke,when I correct it, the error disappeared,but I don't konwn how this happend?

Comment: Nice work xyz. Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 98):

The root cause is that when debugging the java debug interface will call the toString() of your class to show the class information in the pop up box, so if the toString method is not defined correctly, this may happen.

Comment: What if the toString method isn't defined at all? I'm getting it in the RestTemplate class of the Spring jar, that's one of the core classes, and it doesn't have toString() method. Still I'm getting this exception from another class where I'm calling RestTemplate.getForObject(). I'm clueless what's happening.

Comment: @SaurabhPatil `toString` is always defined as all objects extend `java.lang.Object`. One possibility with Spring is that scoped beans are proxied if they are injected into singletons. If `toString` is called on the wrong thread(e.g. one not associated with request context) then the proxy would throw an exception when calling `toString` on it.

Answer (score 30):

I also had a similar exception when debugging in Eclipse. When I moused-over an object, the pop up box displayed an `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException` message. The root cause for me was not the `toString()` method of my class, but rather the `hashCode()` method. It was causing a `NullPointerException`, which caused the `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException` to appear during debugging. Once I took care of the null pointer, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 18):

Well, it might be because of several things as mentioned by others before and after. In my case the problem was same but reason was something else.

In a class (A), I had several objects and one of object was another class (B) with some other objects. During the process, one of the object (String) from class B was null, and then I tried to access that object via parent class (A).

Thus, console will throw **null point exception** but eclipse debugger will show above mentioned error.

I hope you can do the remaining.

Comment: @novice This is the same issue i am facing.How to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue because I was using Lombok @Data annotation that was creating toString and hashcode methods in class files, so I removed @Data annotation and used specific @Gettter @Setter annotation that fixed my issue.

we should use @Data only when we need all @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter on all fields, and @Setter on all non-final fields, and @RequiredArgsConstructor.

Comment: it resolved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For me the same exception was thrown when the toString was defined as such:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ListElem [next=" + next + ", data=" + data + "]";
}
```

Where `ListElem` is a linked list element and I created a `ListElem` as such:

```
private ListElem<Integer> cyclicLinkedList = new ListElem<>(3);
ListElem<Integer> cyclicObj = new ListElem<>(4);
...

cyclicLinkedList.setNext(new ListElem<Integer>(2)).setNext(cyclicObj)
    .setNext(new ListElem<Integer>(6)).setNext(new ListElem<Integer>(2)).setNext(cyclicObj);
```

This effectively caused a cyclic linked list that cannot be printed. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

so I had same problem here. Found out that my domain instance was getting detached from the hibernate session. I used `isAttached()` to check and attached the domain using `d.attach()`

Answer (score 3):

Disabling 'Show Logical Structure' button/icon of the upper right corner of the variables window in the eclipse debugger resolved it, in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue once. In my case toString() method was badly created. TO be precise a static final variable was included in the toString method when a developer form my team was assigned code cleaning task and to add toString(), hashCode() code and equals()  methods to domain objects where ever possible. but in of the classes because of  over looking at it, he included final static variable that caused the "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException" this exception was visible on debugging only when I hovered over the object which has the exception.

Answer (score 3):

This was my case

I had a entity **Student** which was having **many-to-one** relation with another entity **Classes** (the classes which he studied).

I wanted to save the data into another table, which was having **foreign keys** of both **Student** and **Classes**. At some instance of execution, I was bringing a **List** of **Students** under some conditions, and each **Student** will have a reference of **Classes** class.

Sample code :-

```
Iterator<Student> itr = studentId.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) 
{
    Student student = (Student) itr.next();
    MarksCardSiNoGen bo = new MarksCardSiNoGen();

    bo.setStudentId(student);

    Classes classBo = student.getClasses();

    bo.setClassId(classBo);
}
```

Here you can see that, I'm setting both **Student** and **Classes** reference to the **BO** I want to save. But while debugging when I inspected `student.getClasses()` it was showing this exception(`com.sun.jdi.InvocationException`).

The problem I found was that, after fetching the **Student** list using **HQL** query, I was **flushing** and **closing** the **session**. When I removed that `session.close();` statement the problem was solved.

The session was closed when I finally saved all the data into table(**MarksCardSiNoGen**).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I got similar exception in Eclipse. This was due to  `java.lang.StackOverflowError` error. I had overriden `toString()` method in child class, having `JoinColumn`, which was returning string using object of parentclass, resulting in circular dependency. Try to remove that object from `toString()`, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `hashCode()` and `equals()` solved my issue. In my case, I used Apache's commons-lang hash code and equals builders for creating non-static classes manually, so the compiler didn't throw any exception. But at runtime it caused the invocation exception.

Answer (score 1):

I have received `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method` when I lazy loaded entity field which used secondary database config ([Spring Boot with 2 database configs - lazy loading with second config does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424490/spring-boot-with-2-database-configs-lazy-loading-with-second-config-does-not-w)). Temporary solution was to add `FetchType.EAGER`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two reasons an element doesn't exist:

1. Bad xpath (//*[@id'forgotQuote])
2. Correct xpath but no element (//*[contains(text(),'This text is not in the page')])

**Would you get com.sun.jdi.InvocationException in either case when you are running Debug and you hover your mouse over a reference to the WeBElement (this with Selenium and Java)???**

We use the following, but can't distinguish if it returns false due to bad xpath or non-existent element (valid xpath syntax):

```
public static boolean isElementDisplayed(WebElement element) {
    boolean isDisplayed = false;

    try {
        isDisplayed = element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        ;// No Worries
    }
    return isDisplayed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to the object reference getting stale.
I was automating my application using selenium webdriver, so i type something into a text box and then it navigates to another page, so while i come back on the previous page , that object gets stale.
So this was causing the exception, I handled it by again initialising the elements - 
PageFactory.initElements(driver, Test.class;

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. In my case I was hitting a `java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException`. I figured this out only after putting a `printStackTrace` call. I resolved it by changing my code as shown below.

from:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("***** Test Details *****\n");
String.format("[Test: %1]", sb.toString());
```

to:

```
String.format("[Test: %s]", sb.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem once. In my case it was because of overridden `equals` method. One values was coming `null`.