# com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method error in ognlRuntime

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

I am getting "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method" error when I debug in eclipse and is in ognlRuntime.
The error occured when I am passing a value from jsp to the action class.

This is the code in jsp for passing the value

```
<s:textfield name="partReplace.part.number" cssStyle="width:50px;" value ="%{partReplace.part.number}"/></td>
```

and when I enter vlue in that textfield it is not setting in the action class. I debuuged and found the "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method" error in ognlRuntime and it is not taking the value..

Comment: Do you have mutators for the action attributes?

Comment: yes I do have the mutators,but eventhough I enter it is taking null value...

Comment: Show us the action. We expect to see the action having a get AND set for a partReplace Property, which has a getter AND setter for a part property and the part has a getter AND setter for number. Both the getter and setter are required in the action (a setter is not enough).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be the same of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123628/com-sun-jdi-invocationexception-occurred-invoking-method);

if so, the guilty should be an incorrect override of the `toString()` method of your class, invoked by the Eclipse Debugger.

Correct your custom toString() method, or block him from throwing exceptions (a big `try-catch` inside) or remove it completely, and retry.

P.S: this is the first result on Google searching your Exception... and is on SO too :|