# com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method invoking to get string

Tags: java, json

I am getting exception

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.
```

when

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

response is a json result.

Comment: Maybe result is null, what about debugging ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method in JDK8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541283/com-sun-jdi-invocationexception-occurred-invoking-method-in-jdk8)

Comment: I debugged it.
getting null pointer exception as well