# Spring Boot with 2 database configs - lazy loading with second config does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, lazy-loading, transactionmanager

I have Spring Boot project with 2 database configs.

Primary DB config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager", entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory", basePackages = { "com.example.repository.primary" })
public class PrimaryDbConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.primary.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,         @Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.example.domain.primary").persistenceUnit("primary-persistence-unit").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

And secondary:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager", basePackages = { "com.example.repository.secondary" })
public class SecondaryDbConfig {

    @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondary.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,         @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.example.domain.secondary").persistenceUnit("secondary-persistence-unit").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("secondaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

There is entity which is loaded with second DB:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Company> companies;
```

Using:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

When I use `UserRepository`, `User` is retrieved but when I hit to load companies, I get `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.` - [com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123628/com-sun-jdi-invocationexception-occurred-invoking-method). If I change `SecondaryDbConfig` to `@Primary` or add `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` then companies are retrieved as expected. I have tried adding `@Transactional(transactionManager="secondaryTransactionManager")` but it didn't help.

What did I miss? What's the proper approach to lazy load entity properties when using not primary database config?

Comment: Do you add fetch eager to primary ? Does it work properly then. In the repository how do you tell it to use the secondary db config?

Comment: Lazy loading works well when I change secondary DB config to @Primary. In repository I don't specify anything except query methods. Config should specify which DB, transaction manager, entity manager should be used in specific package.

Comment: @JustinasJakavonis May I know, how did you fix this issue, we are facing same issue

Comment: @Premraj - don't remember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by adding @Transactional over @Service class.

Comment: Did you need to specify transactionManager?

Comment: no.. transactionManager we specified package level..

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. To enable lazy loading of JPA entity with multiple databases, you need to create seperate OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter beans for each database in your DBConfig classes.
I found the solution here:
[spring-boot-jpa-multiple-data-sources](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-boot-jpa-multiple-data-sources-example.html)
Search for the term "Lazy" in the article above.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add @Transactional to your @Service method(s) or controller which retrieved list of company.

Good luck!