# com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method osgi aem read subservice

Tags: java, osgi, aem, jcr

I get a nullpointer exception in error logs when I use subservice to read a template's details in AEM 6.4

map.get gives null-pointer exception

with error message as

> com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUsePojo Failed to activate Use class
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.jcr.RepositoryException:
>   This session has been closed.     at
>   org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrValueMap.readFully(JcrValueMap.java:395)
>   [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.8]     at
>   org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrValueMap.entrySet(JcrValueMap.java:183)
>   [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.8]     at
>   com.mysite.core.helpers.AnalyticsHelper.activate(AnalyticsHelper.java:138)
>   [mysite-core:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]  at
>   com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUsePojo.init(WCMUsePojo.java:86)
>   [com.adobe.cq.sightly.cq-wcm-sightly-extension:1.5.12]

it ran fine in AEM 6.3, but in AEM 6.4, it gives null pointer exception

the map is null . It works fine when I remove closing the resourceresolver

```
MysiteReadTemplateService mysiteReadTemplateService = getSlingScriptHelper()
                .getService(MysiteReadTemplateService .class);
        ValueMap map = mysiteReadTemplateService 
                .fetchTemplateDetails(templatePath);
        if (map != null) {
            templateName = map.get("jcr:title", "");
            templateDescription = map.get("jcr:description", "");
        }
```

inside fetchTemplateDetails method -

```
Map<String,Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
          //Mention the subServiceName that is configured in the User Mapping
          paramMap.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "mysitereadservice");
          log.info("After the param");
          ResourceResolver rr = null;
          ValueMap map =null;
          try{
                rr = resourceFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(paramMap);
                log.info("UserId : " + rr.getUserID());
                Resource templateResource = rr.getResource(templatePath);
                log.info("Resource : " + templateResource.getPath());
                map = templateResource.getValueMap();  
                rr.close();
          }catch(Exception e){
                log.error(e.getMessage());
          }
          return map;
```

when rr.close is commented, map is not null in analyticshelper class.

possible explanation is provided in

[com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123628/com-sun-jdi-invocationexception-occurred-invoking-method)

but still, we want to close the resourceresolver as not closing it will create many unclosed sessions .

If anybody faced same issue, could you please let us know your thoughts, or how can I refactor the code so that we are able to close resource resolver as well as the map is not null.

Comment: ValueMap, Resource and etc is unavailable after you close session, put data from 
ValueMap into any data structure like HashMap and use it in another method/class

Answer (score 0):

You can't access resources or properties(ValueMap) after you closed the sesssion/resourceResolver. Put your data into another data structure(Collection, Map) and return it. Or perform your actions while session is opened:

```
Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>;
ResourceResolver rr = null;

try{
    Map<String,Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    //Mention the subServiceName that is configured in the User Mapping
    paramMap.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "mysitereadservice");
    log.info("After the param");
    rr = resourceFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(paramMap);

    if (rr != null) {
        log.info("UserId : " + rr.getUserID());

        Resource templateResource = rr.getResource(templatePath);

        if (templateResource != null) {
            log.info("Resource : " + templateResource.getPath());
            ValueMap map = templateResource.getValueMap();  

            result.put("jcr:title", map.get("jcr:title",""))
            result.put(......);
            result.put(......);
            result.put(......);
            result.put(......);
            result.put(......);
        }
    }
}catch(LoginException e){
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    if (rr != null && !rr.isLive()) {
        rr.close();
    }
}

return result;
```

ResourceResulver should be closed in finally block, or use try-with-resources:

```
try (ResourceResolver rr = resourceFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(paramMap)) {
    //yourCode
} catch (LoginException e) {
    log.errror(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```